# Using a spatial query to filter the atlas pages in QGIS

Tags: qgis, atlas, spatial-query

I would need to create an atlas of all the map sheets (red rectangles) that refer to a specific municipal territory (for example the selected yellow polygon) as in the image. The atlas coverage layer is the map sheet layer.
I try to understand if there is a possibility to use a simpler and more automatic way than using an expression like

```
"Map_Sheet_number" IN ('459090', '459100', 459130, '459140')
```

as in the example, to filter the atlas coverage layer.
[image]

Is it possible (and how) to use a spatial query to filter the atlas coverage layer (map sheets) using another layer (municipal territory)?

Comment: Some more information on what exactly you are trying to achieve, what data you have at hand etc. would be helpful in order to get behind your problem. Currently it is - at least for me - rather hard to fathom what and how you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to clarify the question.

Comment: It may not be possible the number of municipalities but you could add a field to your Atlas (map sheets) layer for each municipality which says whether or not it intersects. So there would be a field "Olmedo" which would be set to TRUE or FALSE, so '459090', '459100', 459130, '459140' would all be set to TRUE and the rest would be FALSE. Then for the expression you could use   "Olmedo" IS TRUE

Comment: But in this way, if I understand correctly, I should insert a new field for each municipal territory of which I would like to generate an atlas?